# Instead of icon , text is coming in mat-step in Angular6

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-material-6, mat-stepper

I am trying to implement Angular Material's stepper.I am just following "https://stackblitz.com/angular/maxbjapeayr?file=app%2Fstepper-states-example.ts" this  and doing. But why i am not able to see icon here. And if i want to add custom icon how to add here. Please help me here as i am not getting any proper solutions. [image]

Comment: Have you included the google fonts style sheet in your index.html?

Comment: Oh my bad.yes included now . icon is coming. But how to add our own custom icon ?@DarrenLamb

Comment: You mean change the icon in the stepper to another material icon?

Comment: yes , i have already one icon , i want to add that icon instead of "pen" icon

Comment: Not sure how you would replace it with a custom icon, only how you would replace it with one from the material library. I suggest updating your question to reflect your new problem and describe what you've done to try and resolve it.

Comment: Okay. Thank you for your time.@Darren Lamb